# Problema con script

Tags: javascript, html

me encuentro realizando un formulario de registro pero me encuentro con un problema, lo que pasa es que al iniciar el formulario me muestra los campos "CECO", "DIRECCION", "LIDER". Lo cual no deberia de ser de esa manera, lo que busco es que al iniciar solo me muestre "usuario" y "contraseña" y si me selecciona algun rol pues ahí si me muestre los otros campos. Otro problema que encuentro es en el boton ya que al tener una etiqueta `<a>`solo me toma el boton si le seleeciono en "regresar", si selecciono en el area del boton (no en el texto) no me lo toma. Cualquier ayuda es muy bien recibida. Gracias

Adjunto el codigo del formulario junto con el script utilizado:

```js
      function comprobar(){
      var etiqueta = document.getElementById('datos');
      var source = document.getElementById('rol');

        if(source.selectedIndex >=1)
        {
          etiqueta.style.display = 'block';

        }
        else
        {
          etiqueta.style.display = 'none';
                    $('#datos').removeAttr('style');
                      $('#datos').hide();
        }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/styleRegister.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"&amp;gt;>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Script para mostrar campos dependiendo de elección select-->
 

</head>
<body>
  <section class="register-block">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 register-sec">
        <h2 class="text-center">Registro</h2>
        <form class="register-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('registro') }}" >
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Usuario</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el usuario">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la contraseña">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1" onclick="comprobar()">Seleccione el Rol
            <select class="form-control" id="rol" name="rol" required >
              <option>----</option>
              <option >Lab Metrología</option>
              <option >Lab Aguas y Suelos</option>
              <option >Lab Catálisis</option>
              <option >Lab Análisis petrofísicos</option>
              <option >Lab CEMIM</option>
              <option >Lab CIT</option>
              <option >Lab Biotecnología</option>
              <option >Lab Cromatografía</option>
              <option >Lab Crudos</option>
              <option >Lab Daños a la Formación</option>
              <option >Lab Espectroscopía</option>
              <option >Lab Fenómenos Interfaciales y Reología</option>
              <option >Lab Geoquímica</option>
              <option >Lab Materiales</option>
              <option >Lab Mecánica de Rocas</option>
              <option >Lab Motores</option>
              <option >Lab Procesamiento Geológico</option>
              <option >Lab PVT</option>
              <option >Lab Química de Producción</option>
              <option >Lab Recobro Mejorado</option>
              <option >Litóteca</option>
              <option >Mantenimiento</option>
              <option >Plantas Piloto</option>
              <option>admin</option>

            </select>
          </label>
          

          <p id="datos" >
            <label>
              
              <label>CECO</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ceco" placeholder="Ingrese el codigo ceco">

              <label>Direccion</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="direccion" placeholder="Ingrese la dirección">

              <label>Lider</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lider" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del lider">
             

            </label>
          </p>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 banner-sec">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
```

Gracias.

Comment: lanza la función al cargar el script, hasta abajo del script añade ```comprobar()```

Comment: @Charls Sigue igual amigo

Comment: Deberías cargar jQuery y después bootstrap, tal como se ve ahí vas a tener problemas porque jQuery es una dependencia de Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente la función comprobar se manda a llamar cuando el script es cargado,
y el problema del botón solo sería invertir las etiquetas para que la etiqueta `a` abarque a el botón.

```js
function comprobar(){
      var etiqueta = document.getElementById('datos');
      var source = document.getElementById('rol');

        if(source.selectedIndex >=1)
        {
          etiqueta.style.display = 'block';

        }
        else
        {
          etiqueta.style.display = 'none';
                    $('#datos').removeAttr('style');
                      $('#datos').hide();
        }
      }
      
      comprobar();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/styleRegister.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"&amp;gt;>
  
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Script para mostrar campos dependiendo de elección select-->
 

</head>
<body>
  <section class="register-block">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 register-sec">
        <h2 class="text-center">Registro</h2>
        <form class="register-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('registro') }}" >
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Usuario</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el usuario">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la contraseña">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1" onclick="comprobar()">Seleccione el Rol
            <select class="form-control" id="rol" name="rol" required >
              <option>----</option>
              <option >Lab Metrología</option>
              <option >Lab Aguas y Suelos</option>
              <option >Lab Catálisis</option>
              <option >Lab Análisis petrofísicos</option>
              <option >Lab CEMIM</option>
              <option >Lab CIT</option>
              <option >Lab Biotecnología</option>
              <option >Lab Cromatografía</option>
              <option >Lab Crudos</option>
              <option >Lab Daños a la Formación</option>
              <option >Lab Espectroscopía</option>
              <option >Lab Fenómenos Interfaciales y Reología</option>
              <option >Lab Geoquímica</option>
              <option >Lab Materiales</option>
              <option >Lab Mecánica de Rocas</option>
              <option >Lab Motores</option>
              <option >Lab Procesamiento Geológico</option>
              <option >Lab PVT</option>
              <option >Lab Química de Producción</option>
              <option >Lab Recobro Mejorado</option>
              <option >Litóteca</option>
              <option >Mantenimiento</option>
              <option >Plantas Piloto</option>
              <option>admin</option>

            </select>
          </label>
          

          <p id="datos" >
            <label>
              
              <label>CECO</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ceco" placeholder="Ingrese el codigo ceco">

              <label>Direccion</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="direccion" placeholder="Ingrese la dirección">

              <label>Lider</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lider" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del lider">
             

            </label>
          </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-register float-right">Registrar</button>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check"  style="margin-right: 100px">
           <a style="color:#ffffff;" href="{{ route('lab.index') }}">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-register float-right" >Regresar</button>
           </a>
          </div>

        </form>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 banner-sec">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
```